# Xamarin.Forms: How to put a native iOS class which implements DependencyService interface to an separate iOS library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a native iOS class which implements the Xamarin.Forms DependencyService, since I want to reuse this class in different projects, so I would like to extract this class from my current Xamarin.iOS app to a separate Xamarin.iOS library.

### Here is my current project structure:

BDNC (Xamarin.Forms)

---IHTBluetoothManager (DependencyService Interface)

BDNC.iOS (Xamarin.iOS)

---HTBluetoothManager : IHTBluetoothManager (DependencyService Implementation)

### I want to achieve something like:

BDNC (Xamarin.Forms)

---IHTBluetoothManager (DependencyService Interface)

BDNC.iOS (Xamarin.iOS App)

--- App codes

HTBluetoothKit (Xamarin.iOS Library)

---HTBluetoothManager : IHTBluetoothManager (DependencyService Implementation)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **SharedProject** will fit your request. Right click your solution => Add Project => at Visual C# column find the Shared Project:

[image]

In this shared project you can implement your interface:

```
public class MyImplementClass : IHTBluetoothManager
{
    public void DoSome()
    {                
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

At last when you want to use this **DependencyService**, add this shared project to your solution. Then right click your ios project's reference => Add References => at Shared Project Tab click the shared project we just added.

Moreover we also need to add interface class ( IHTBluetoothManager ) in your PCL to make it work well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems that is a feasible solution, but I am using .Net standard library for my other libraries, can they work together?

Comment: and the shared project has to be an iOS project, because I need to use native iOS code in the implementation.

Comment: They can work together. And shared project contains both iOS and Android code. You can try it.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I was in the exam week and forgot to check this post. Yes, you solutions works, I just simply extract the native ios Bluetooth code from.iOS and put it on the shared project, and everything works as expected. That's cool, I really appreciate your help: )

Comment: By the way, could you please tell me what limits of using shared projects I should be aware of? Like the performance and compatibility.

Comment: This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing) may help you.

Comment: Hi @HaoyuanTang, If this worked for you, please mark this as an answer to help other communities learn about this.

Answer (score 0):

I may be answering the wrong question so please don't hesitate to redirect me.  The key here is in how you setup the references in each project.  If **BDNC** is a Xamarin.Forms cross platform project and **BDNC.iOS** is your iOS platform implementation project you can think of **BDNC.iOS** as where everything comes together.

In other words, **BDNC.iOS** needs to reference **BDNC** in order to get the Xamarin.Forms Models and ViewModels for the iOS app.  Likewise, in order for **BDNC.iOS** to implement the `IHTBluetoothManager` for iOS, it needs to call methods in **HTBluetoothManager**.  So, **BDNC.iOS** needs to reference **HTBluetoothManager**.

When you create a cross-platform application using VisualStudio 2017 (Mac or Windows) it creates the reference to **BDNC** in **BCNC.iOS** for you.  So the only thing you'll have to do is create the reference to **HTBlueToothManager** in **BCNC.iOS**:
 - In Mac, in the solution explorer pad, expand the **BDNC.iOS** project and right click on the **References** folder and select **Edit References...* from the popup menu.  The **Edit References** dialog will appear.  Click on the **Projects** tab, select the **HTBluetoothManager** project, and click **[OK]** to finish.
 - On PC, in the solution explorer pad, expand the **BDNC.iOS** project and right click on the **References** folder and select **Add Reference...* from the popup menu.  The **Reference Manager** dialog will appear.  Click on the **Projects** section (left bar), select the **HTBluetoothManager** project, and click **[OK]** to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I want to achieve is to separate the actual bluetooth code from the BDNC.iOS, so that I can reuse this part for different projects. I tried referencing BDNC interface in my separate bluetooth library, unfortunately that didn't work, the app will throw an exception. So now I still put everything inside BDNC.iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is create a simple project and add your dependencies and code there for each platform.

Xamarin has access to native libraries and you can add whatever you need and work with the API of any library.

After that, you can create a nuget package which than you can use in all your other projects and share it with others if you want